# BeautifulSoup soup.find tag

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to parse some pages, I just don't get one thing, 
I'm parsing block "div" with the class "pager rel clr'"

```
pages=soup.find('div', class_='pager rel clr')
```

From this code, I just need to parse following href's page links

```
https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=2
https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=3
https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=4
```

Here is an incomplete sample of the html fetched

```
<div class="pager rel clr">
<form action="" class="abs clr pagerGoToPage" id="pagerGoToPage" method="GET">
<span class="fnormal small fleft lheight24 pding0_5">Idź do strony:</span>
<fieldset class="fleft">
<input class="light lheight22 fleft tcenter br3 {currentPage: 1}" id="pageParam" maxlength="4" name="page" type="text" value="1"/>
<input name="search[filter_enum_model]" type="hidden" value="golf"/>
<input class="{totalPages: 219}" type="submit" value="OK"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<span class="fbold prev abs large">
<span class="link pageNextPrev {page:0}" data-cy="page-link-prev"> <span>« poprzednia</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="item fleft">
<span class="block br3 c41 large tdnone lheight24 current" data-cy="page-link-current"> <span>1</span>
</span>
</span>
<span class="item fleft">
<a class="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24" data-cy="page-link-2" href="https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=2">
<span>2</span>
</a>
</span>
<span class="item fleft">
<a class="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24" data-cy="page-link-3" href="https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=3">
<span>3</span>
</a>
</span>
<span class="item fleft">
<a class="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24" data-cy="page-link-4" href="https://www.olx.pl/motoryzacja/samochody/volkswagen/golf/?page=4">
<span>4</span>
</a>
```

Comment: can you provide the code that gets you this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see everything clear, once you have your beautiful soup with all the tags, you can do something like this

```
for a in soup.find('div', class_='pager rel clr').find_all('a', href=True, class_="block br3 brc8 large tdnone lheight24"):
    print(a['href'])
```